# Problem with jQuery Draggable

Tags: jquery, draggable

I'm having trouble getting the very last draggable item in the loop below to become draggable (all the other items before the last item are fine, they are draggable). The html it's outputting to my browser for the last draggable item looks fine when I view source exept for the very last draggable, the "ui-draggable" class isnt being attached to the div (when looking with firebug). Any ideas? Thanks

```
            <?php foreach ($categorySliderImages->result() as $idx => $row): ?>
            <li>
            <div class="slider">
            <div class="slide">
                <h2><?= $row->Header ?></h2>
                <div><?= $row->Teaser ?></div>
                <p><a href="/products/product/<?= $row->PID; ?>/<?= $row->FID; ?>">Click Here</a> for more information</p>
            </div>
            <?php $subImages = $this->products_model->get_category_slider_images($row->PID); ?>
            <?php foreach ($subImages->result() as $idx2 => $row): ?>
            <div id="catdraggable<?= $row->IID ?>" style="position: absolute; top:<?= $row->SliderTop ?>px; left:<?= $row->SliderLeft ?>px;">
                <img src="/FLPRODIMGS/thumb/<?= $row->Name ?>" />
            </div>                 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $("#catdraggable<?= $row->IID ?>").draggable({
                        stop: function (event, ui) {
                            p = $("#catdraggable<?= $row->IID ?>").position();
                            $.post("/admin/set_slider_image_position", {
                                id: '<?= $row->IID ?>',
                                top: p.top,
                                left: p.left,
                                context: 'cat'
                            })
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </li>
```

Comment: It's a little strange to use $row as the value of the key-value pair for both of the foreach loops. Even if that's not the problem, it's not a very good idea.

Comment: You're right, and I've changed the second one to row2 but still having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will fix your problem, but at the very least it will reduce the size of your page a little: instead of the script being repeated for each loop iteration, move it outside the foreachs, and add a class to the divs that you want to make draggable.
So something like:

```
<div class="yourclass" data-yourid="<?= $row->IID ?>" id="catdraggable<?= $row->IID ?>" style="position: absolute; top:<?= $row->SliderTop ?>px; left:<?= $row->SliderLeft ?>px;">
```

The `data-yourid` attribute is so you can read it later, and it's valid HTML5.
And at the end, the following script (only one time, i.e. after the `endforeach`s):

```
$(function () {
    $(".yourclass").draggable({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            p = $(this).position();
            $.post("/admin/set_slider_image_position", {
                id: $(this).attr("data-yourid"),
                top: p.top,
                left: p.left,
                context: 'cat'
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This makes the last one draggable but for some reason posts the same id no matter which one Im dragging.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to change one of the $row to $row2. Working good now. Thank You.

Comment: Oh man... 2 days and 5 headaches later and it finally works. Still don't know why it wouldn't work as I originally had it, granted the code wasn't as clean as it could have been but it still should have worked. At this point Im just glad its working now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing your target draggable elements in a containing div and have jQuery reference that.  This makes your declaration a little cleaner:

```
    <div id="draggable">
        <div id="drag-<?= $row->IID ?>" style="position: absolute; top:<?= $row->SliderTop ?>px; left:<?= $row->SliderLeft ?>px;">
            <img src="/FLPRODIMGS/thumb/<?= $row->Name ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

You then get this for your jQuery statement:

```
$(function () {
       $("#draggable div").draggable({
              stop: function (event, ui) {
                    p = ui.position;
                    $.post("/admin/set_slider_image_position", {
                                id: ui.helper[0].id,
                                top: p.top,
                                left: p.left,
                                context: 'cat'
                    })
               }
       });
});
```